# Converting $ \int_{1}^{2}\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{x\,dy\,dx} $ to polar coordinates

Tags: multiple-integral

An integral is given.
$$
\int_{1}^{2}\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{x\,dy\,dx}
$$
It is asked to convert it into the polar coordinate system.
The limit of $r$ I have calculated is $0$ to $2$.
I found the following after converting into the polar form.
$$
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\int_{\sec{\theta}}^{2\sec{\theta}}r^2 cos{\theta}\,dr\,d{\theta}
$$
Is my attempt correct?
Also, the value of the double integral in the Cartesian coordinate and that of the polar coordinate are different. Kindly explain.

Comment: The lower limit of $r$ should be defined from the lower limit of $x$ by equation $x=r\cos\theta$. The upper limit of $r$ should be defined from the upper and lower limits of $y$ by equation $x^2+y^2=r^2$.

Comment: Limits of $\theta$ are from $-\pi/3$ to $\pi/3$, or you should twice integral from $0$ to $\pi/3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

If you sketch the region on the plane, it will help you to see what is going on. We have a vertical slice of a circle of radius 2 centered at the origin.

You are correct that the maximum value of $\theta$ is $\frac{\pi}{3}$ but the circle also lies below the $x$-axis so the minimum value of $\theta$ is $-\frac{\pi}{3}$.

For a given value of $\theta=\theta^*$, the maximum value of $r$ is of course 2, but the minimum value occurs at the intersection of the line $\theta=\theta^*$ and the line $x=1$, which is $\sec\theta^*$.

So the integral should be
\begin{align}
\int_{-\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\int_{\sec{\theta}}^2 r^2\cos\theta\ drd\theta.
\end{align}

Comment: I just added a diagram without checking with you. See if you are fine with it.

Comment: Looks great, thanks!